# Query datastax graph vertex in batch of total 50 vertex

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph-databases, datastax-enterprise

We have a vertex named "XYZ". where we have more than 5000+ vertex. We need to extract each vertex id one by one in 50 vertex batch.

We are using the scala play framework and to query the DataStax graph we are using this lib  https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala .

we see some solutions where vertex id is numeric so they query vertex like this g.V(1) and iterate into the loop. But we have id like this "{~label=xyz,uuid=ashchaschasc}". That id is not int so we can not iterate into the incremental loop.

Whats the possible best way to do that we don't want DB query timeout